# ICS Navigation app change default from walking to driving?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus, google-maps-navigation

When I try to add a new "Directions" shortcut to my home screen, the shortcut interface defaults to "walking" directions instead of "driving" directions.
Also, when I use Chrome To Phone to send a directions page to my phone, it shows up in Walking Directions mode.

Is there any way I can change this default, so my phone assumes I'm talking about Driving directions first?
It seems like it would be a better default.

Answer (score 3):

It's to do with the transport mode you're using when you tell maps to ask for directions.  Pick a point on the map.  Press and hold till the bubble comes up.  tap on the bubble, choose directions, now the directions panel comes up with from and to lines and under that will be the choice driving, public transport or walking.  choose driving then press navigation.  that works for me after I was suffering the same problem as you.  Hope this helps